# How to extract text before nth occurrence of special character from the right in lookerstudio

Tags: extract, looker-studio, looker

I have an existing field that I want to use to create a new field. I want to keep the text after the second occurrence of "-" from the right.
This are some values:

| existing value | desired output |
| --- | --- |
| M-1030-SIS422-1029-XS | M-1030-SIS422 |
| JACKSON-0003-28 | JACKSON |

I want to use a regex expression but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expression should work for you. The desired output is in the 1st capture group, the 2nd capture group is used to match the part you need to remove:

```
(.*)(-.*){2}
```

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hPKzF4/2) demo.

**Update**: Google Data Studio function call:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '(.*)(-.*){2}', '\\1')
```

Comment: which function should I use it in? REGEXP_REPLACE or a different one? this give the error Syntax error: Unexpected ".". in google data studio

Comment: @TeundeKort I don't know anything about Google Data Studio but from what I found it seems like this would be the correct function to use: `REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '(.*)(-.*){2}', '\\1')`. Tell me if that works and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @TeundeKort great ! You can upvote and accept answers when they solve your problem. I updated my answer with the function call.